# Lower bound or distribution of shares in Portfolio Optimization python

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, scipy, portfolio

I have to porfolio optimize in python.

I used bounds

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds,

bounds = tuple((0, 0.2) for asset in range(num_assets))
```

But actually i have lower bound equals = 0.05. I would like the results to have portfolios in the range from 0.2 to 0.05 or 0.

Is it possible to do this within this function? Or should I just delete all other such portfolios?

Comment: Such a variable (zero or between L and U) is called a semi-continuous variable. Some solvers handle this directly. It can also be formulated with binary variables. In any case, you most likely need an MIQP (Mixed-Integer Quadratic Programming) solver.

Comment: But I used scipt.minimize(... , method='SLSQP',...) for my task

Comment: Not suited for this problem.

Comment: You could run this solver once for all [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) of assets, which would mean that you would be able to solve it with just SLSQP and bounds (0.05, 0.20). Is the number of assets small enough that this is computationally feasible? How many assets do you have?

Comment: I have 20 assets. When i used (0.05,0.2) I get 0.05 as minimun. But acuallt i dont need that share

Comment: @NickODell suggests implementing a complete enumeration scheme. For n=20 this means 2^20 (about a million) NLPs to solve. (Each variable is either fixed to 0 or between 0.05 and 2: form all combinations). In practice, it is better to use an appropriate solver.